# Can't insert row on DB2 w/ EF5

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, db2

I have a WPF app running against DB2 9.1 (z/OS) using EF5.  Everything works fine except for inserting where the primary key is an INTEGER(10) field.

The entity has the mapped property as an int type.

```
private Models.UserInfo GetUserInfo(String emplID, String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(emplID))
            return null;
        int _emplID = Convert.ToInt32(emplID.Trim());

        try
        {

            using (var ctx = new Data.TIMSContext())
            {
                var user = (from u in ctx.Query<Data.Entities.ASNUser>()
                            where u.EmployeeID == _emplID
                            select u).FirstOrDefault();

                if (user == null)
                {
                    //add user to database
                    user = new Data.Entities.ASNUser()
                    {
                        EmployeeID = _emplID,
                        FirstName = firstName.Trim(),
                        LastName = lastName.Trim()
                    };
                    ctx.Set<Data.Entities.ASNUser>().Add(user);
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                }

                return new Models.UserInfo()
                {
                    EmployeeID = user.EmployeeID,
                    DisplayName = String.Format("{0}, {1}", user.LastName, user.FirstName)
                };
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh, the error is that is can't insert a null value into the column for employee ID.  I don't know why it would be null since the string passed in is a valid number string and after converting, it absolutely does have a value.

Comment: How is this different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31325779/cant-insert-simple-row-into-db2-w-ef5 ?

Comment: because i thought it had started working... but i was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem with your edmx file / EF model.

If the EmployeeID field is defined in the model as a auto increment id, then EF will ignore the value that you set and null will be sent to the database. But the database does not have an auto increment field, so it tries to insert null.

Comment: this was written DB first.  there is no edmx.  the field is not set to auto-increment in the db.